# Python program problems

Tags: python

So I've been working on this python code for a few days now. I'm trying to decode a zero-one code I made previously. Simply put it hides genomic code...

```
binary = raw_input ('Enter binary code:')

binary = binary.replace('00', 'A')
binary = binary.replace('01', 'C')
binary = binary.replace('10', 'G')
binary = binary.replace('11', 'T')

print binary
```

My issue is, it will accept something like 0110 = CG. But when I add any characters after that it messes up, like 011011 should be CGT instead it's C1CC1. If anyone could identify this issue, or even solve it that would be great.

Comment: You have to split the string into 2 character strings and *then* map to ACGT.

Comment: I presume you are not reading two characters at a time as needed.

Comment: `011011` - first your script checks for 'A's - None there. Then we check for 'C's - I see 2 that match, your `binary` becomes `'C1C1'`. Now check 'G' and 'T', nothing matches. Your script has nothing to tell it to only look at groups of 2.

Comment: You cannot use `replace()` on the whole string like that because nothing ensures that the replacements will adhere to the needed two-character units.  Instead, consume the string two characters at a time, and translate those two-character units.

Answer (score 4):

Repeatedly take off two characters and decode them

```
s = "100101001010101010110"

decode = {'00':'A', '01':'C', '10':'G', '11':'T'}

while s:
    (code, s) = (s[:2], s[2:])
    print decode[code]
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution to ForceBru's, using the `re` module:

```
import re    
dna = '100010101001010111000'

base_pairs = {'00': 'A', '01': 'C', '10':'G', '11': 'T'}

alpha_dna = ''.join([base_pairs[x] for x in re.findall('..?', dna)])

# alpha_dna == 'GAGGGCCCTA'
```

Comment: replace dna[x] wirh base_pairs[x]

Answer (score 0):

In the following code error checking is omitted for the sake of clarity

```
a='011011'
rep={'00': 'A','01': 'C','10':'G','11': 'T'}
res=''

for x in xrange(0,len(a),2):
    res+=rep[a[x]+a[x+1]]

print res
```

Here you just have to split the string into some blocks of length 2 and then use each of these blocks as a key of a dictionary.

Comment: You do realize that you're wasting a lot of cpu cycles on generating indices (at 4 bytes / index) to index into an array where the elements are 1-byte small? And then index the array *twice*, to extract the individual characters?

Comment: @haavee these are strings so they are not one byte small. Call sys.getsizeof() and you can see they are bigger than that

Comment: @haavee, this code was written to show _the algorithm_, to be as simple as possible and as legible as possible. I wasn't aiming for very effective code, I was aiming for code that's easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

One liner! Probably not useful, but just for fun:

```
"".join([ {'00':'A', '01':'C', '10':'G', '11':'T'}[code] for code in [ binary[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(binary),2) ]])
```

Yes, I'm addicted to list comprehensions.